# FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Download/ - Android Oreo

Tags: android, filenotfoundexception, sharing

I have an app. There is an imageview. Image loads from Url and also there is a button for sharing image. 
when i press share button i got below error.

> java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   /storage/emulated/0/Download/share_image_1536343274460.png (Permission
>   denied)

my manifest xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="50"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="50"/>

<provider
    android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="com.xxxx.fileprovider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
</provider>
```

provider_paths xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

This is my java code

```
btnShare.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        if (isReadStorageAllowed() == true) {
           onShareItem();
        }
        else
        {
            requestStoragePermission();
        }
    }
});

public void onShareItem() {
    // Get access to bitmap image from view
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);

    // Get access to the URI for the bitmap
    Uri bmpUri = getLocalBitmapUri(imageView);
    if (bmpUri != null) {
        //outfile is the path of the image stored in the gallery
        // Construct a ShareIntent with link to image
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
        shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bmpUri);
        shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        shareIntent.setType("image/*");
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,marketLink);
        // Launch sharing dialog for image
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share Image"));
    } else {
         // ...sharing failed, handle error
    } 
}

public Uri getLocalBitmapUri(ImageView imageView) {
    Drawable drawable = imageView.getDrawable();
    Bitmap bmp = null;
    if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable){
        bmp = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    } else {
        return null;
    }
    // Store image to default external storage directory
    Uri bmpUri = null;
    try {
        File file =  new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "share_image_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
        out.close();
        bmpUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return bmpUri;
}
```

Comment: Is this Image on the SD Card?

Comment: @UmangBurman , image loads from url.

Comment: Okay, So what does the button do?

Comment: `System.currentTimeMillis()` change everytime. I think file name not changing every time right?

Comment: @FaysalAhmed this works fine before oreo. I mean, this works fine all devices but not in oreo.

Comment: @UmangBurman when i press btnShare,  onShareItem()  methods works.

Comment: OKay, Does it store the image which loads from URL in SD Card?

Comment: @UmangBurman Picasso.with(this).load(url)
                .memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE, MemoryPolicy.NO_STORE)
                .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE)
                .into(imageView);

Comment: Oh Okay.. So What is the issue?

Comment: @UmangBurman java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Download/share_image_1536343274460.png (Permission denied)

Comment: I'm getting confused here. According to the question you get this error, but you said you load a Image from URL in ImageView. Right.? So How does this error relate to URL?

Comment: @UmangBurman I am getting error on this line FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);

Comment: Okay.. In which Android Version are you trying

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **`FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "provider authority from manifest", file);`** instead of **`Uri.fromFile(file)`** when targeting above API level 24 and above.

Your main change will be in method `getLocalBitmapUri()` @ this line:

```
bmpUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
```

> So change like
>
> *If (above API 24 ) then use*
>
> ```
> FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "provider authority from manifest", file);
> ```
>
> *else old approach.*

Comment: I'm Sorry but How does this relate to Permission Denied thingy?

Comment: It's because you're having file provider from manifest file, so that app will not crash on `FileUriExposed` exception. But you're still receiving URI using old API of URI class. While it has changes from SDK 24, so that we need to use `FileProvider` class to get our URI.

Comment: Oh, I see. So, I hope this is the solution then.

Comment: You can try it yourself.

Comment: No, Thanks, I have other things to do. :)

Comment: @JeelVankhede i got error on FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);

Comment: @JeelVankhede i changed bmpUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(), "com.myapap.fileprovider", file);

Comment: Are you requesting runtime permission before accessing file from external storage? Just allow runtime permission and try.

Comment: @JeelVankhede i asked permission when user press btnShare button.